# What is the simplest non-convex polytope with strictly triangular faces?

Tags: geometry

What is the simplest (in terms of the number of faces) non-convex polytope with strictly triangular faces?  Please note that "non-convex" also means non-weakly-convex.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Six faces: a tertrahedron with a smaller tetrahedron (same base face, but less tall) subtracted.
Or another: Slightly raise two opposite vertices of the base of a quadratic pyramid.

The number of faces must be even if all are triangles, hence the next smaller candidate has four faces, but that is necessarily a tetrahedron.